# Changing default encoding of Python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, console

I have many "can't encode" and "can't decode" problems with [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) when I run my applications from the console. But in the [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) [PyDev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyDev) IDE, the default character encoding is set to [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), and I'm fine.

I searched around for setting the default encoding, and people say that Python deletes the `sys.setdefaultencoding` function on startup, and we can not use it.

So what's the best solution for it?

Comment: See the blog post *[The Illusive setdefaultencoding](http://blog.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html)*.

Comment: `The best solution is to learn to use encode and decode correctly instead of using hacks.` This was certainly possible with *python2* at the cost of always remembering to do so / consistently using your own interface. My experience suggests that this becomes highly problematic when you are writing code that you want to work with both python2 and python3.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Here is a simpler method (hack) that gives you back the `setdefaultencoding()` function that was deleted from `sys`:

```
import sys
# sys.setdefaultencoding() does not exist, here!
reload(sys)  # Reload does the trick!
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

(Note for Python 3.4+: `reload()` is in the `importlib` library.)

**This is not a safe thing to do**, though: this is obviously a hack, since `sys.setdefaultencoding()` is purposely removed from `sys` when Python starts. Reenabling it and changing the default encoding [can break code that relies on ASCII being the default](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/) (this code can be third-party, which would generally make fixing it impossible or dangerous).

PS: This hack doesn't seem to work with Python 3.9 anymore.

Comment: I downvoted, because that answer doesn't help for running existing applications (which is one way to interpret the question), is wrong when you are writing/maintaining an application and dangerous when writing a library. The right way is to set `LC_CTYPE` (or in an application, check whether it is set right and abort with a meaningful error message).

Comment: @ibotty I do agree that this answer is a hack and that it is dangerous to use it. It does answer the question, though ("Changing default encoding of Python?"). Do you have a reference about the effect of the environment variable LC_CTYPE on the Python interpreter?

Comment: well, it did not mention, it's a hack at first. other than that, dangerous answers that lack any mention that they are, are not helpful.

Comment: @EOL, and the references re LC_CTYPE: https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html

Comment: @ibotty `LC_CTYPE` is independent from the "default encoding of Python" that the question refers to (`sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns `ascii` for me, with `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`). So, what (different) problem that you have in mind does `LC_CTYPE` solve?

Comment: @EOL you are right. It does effect the preferredencoding though (in python 2 and 3): `LC_CTYPE=C python -c 'import locale; print( locale.getpreferredencoding())'`

Comment: @user2394901 The use of sys.setdefaultencoding() has always been discouraged!! And the encoding of py3k is hard-wired to "utf-8" and changing it raises an error.

Comment: I'm using ipython notebooks, and in my case, as soon as I execute the hack the print function no longer prints to stdout.

Comment: … and print still does not work when setting back the default encoding to 'ascii'… This smells like some magic done by the notebook… In any case, this solution is only a hack, and can thus break.

Comment: Gives me `NameError: name 'reload' is not defined`

Comment: In Python 3.4+, you need to use the `reload()` from the `importlib` library.

Comment: even after the reload:
'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I am observing the same thing with Python 3.9.13 (so I updated this old answer).

Answer (score 99):

If you get this error when you try to pipe/redirect output of your script

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)

Just export `PYTHONIOENCODING` in console and then run your code.

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
```

Comment: This is the only solution that made any difference for me.  - I'm on Debian 7, with broken locale settings. Thanks.

Comment: Set `LC_CTYPE` to something sensible instead. It makes all the other programs happy as well.

Comment: A bigger bug in Python3 is, that `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` is not the default.  This makes scripts break just because `LC_ALL=C`

Comment: `Set LC_CTYPE to something sensible instead` This is a reasonable suggestion. This doesn't work so well when you are trying to distribute code that *just works* on another person's system.

Comment: Debian and Redhat OSes use a `C.utf8` locale to provide more sensible C. glibc upstream is working on adding it, so perhaps we should not be blaming Python for respecting locale settings\…?

Comment: Thank you so much! Spent hours online and eventually came across with your response. Adding that line into `.bashrc` of Cygwin addresses the encoding problem with Python.

Comment: Just to say that I have no problem with pure python 2.7. Only got it when I use python 2.7 with __future__, so I had to use those solutions (PYTHONIOENCODING or sys.reload). No problem neither with python 3.

Comment: Note that Heroku Dynos do NOT have the default encoding set to utf8, which makes for a frustrating debugging experience (cough cough 4 hours until I found this answer...). This solves the problem on Heroku.

Answer (score 53):

**A) To control `sys.getdefaultencoding()` output:**

```
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())'
```

`ascii`

Then

```
echo "import sys; sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-16-be')" > sitecustomize.py
```

and

```
PYTHONPATH=".:$PYTHONPATH" python -c 'import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())'
```

`utf-16-be`

You could put your **sitecustomize.py** higher in your `PYTHONPATH`.

Also  you might like to try [`reload(sys).setdefaultencoding`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python/17628350#17628350) by @EOL

**B) To control `stdin.encoding` and `stdout.encoding` you want to set `PYTHONIOENCODING`:**

```
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.encoding, sys.stdout.encoding)'
```

`ascii ascii`

Then

```
PYTHONIOENCODING="utf-16-be" python -c 'import sys; 
print(sys.stdin.encoding, sys.stdout.encoding)'
```

`utf-16-be utf-16-be`

**Finally:** you can use **A)** or **B)** or **both!**

Comment: (python2 only) separate but interesting is extending above with `from __future__ import unicode_literals` see [discussion](http://python-future.org/imports.html#unicode-literals)

Answer (score 18):

Starting with [PyDev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyDev) 3.4.1, the default encoding is not being changed anymore. 
See [this ticket](https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/315) for details.

For earlier versions a solution is to make sure PyDev does not run with UTF-8 as the default encoding. Under Eclipse, run dialog settings ("run configurations", if I remember correctly); you can choose the default encoding on the common tab. Change it to US-ASCII if you want to have these errors 'early' (in other words: in your PyDev environment). Also see [an original blog post for this workaround](http://opensourcehacker.com/2010/01/24/aptana-studio-eclipse-pydev-default-unicode-encoding/).

Comment: Thanks Chris. Especially considering Mark T's comment above, your answer seems to be the most appropriate to me. And for somebody who's not primarily an Eclipse/PyDev user, I never would have figured that out on my own.

Comment: I'd like to change this globally (rather than once per run configuration), but haven't figured out how - have asked a separate q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394277/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-encoding-for-all-run-configurations-within

Answer (score 13):

Regarding python2 (and python2 only), some of the former answers rely on using the following hack:

```
import sys
reload(sys)  # Reload is a hack
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

It is discouraged to use it (check [this](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script))

In my case, it come with a side-effect: I'm using ipython notebooks, and once I run the code the ´print´ function no longer works. I guess there would be solution to it, but still I think using the hack should not be the correct option.

After trying many options, the one that worked for me was **using the same code in the `sitecustomize.py`, where that piece of code is meant to be**. After evaluating that module, the setdefaultencoding function is removed from sys.

So the solution is to append to file `/usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py` the code:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

When I use virtualenvwrapper the file I edit is `~/.virtualenvs/venv-name/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py`.

And when I use with python notebooks and conda, it is `~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py`

Answer (score 8):

There is an insightful blog post about it.

See https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/.

I paraphrase its content below.

In python 2 which was not as strongly typed regarding the encoding of strings you could perform operations on differently encoded strings, and succeed. E.g. the following would return `True`.

```
u'Toshio' == 'Toshio'
```

That would hold for every (normal, unprefixed) string that was encoded in `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which defaulted to `ascii`, but not others.

The default encoding was meant to be changed system-wide in `site.py`, but not somewhere else. The hacks (also presented here) to set it in user modules were just that: hacks, not the solution.

Python 3 did changed the system encoding to default to utf-8 (when LC_CTYPE is unicode-aware), but the fundamental problem was solved with the requirement to explicitly encode "byte"strings whenever they are used with unicode strings.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the approach I used to produce code that was compatible with both *python2* and *python3* and always produced *utf8* output.  I found this answer elsewhere, but I can't remember the source.

This approach works by replacing `sys.stdout` with something that **isn't quite file-like** (but still only using things in the standard library). This may well cause problems for your underlying libraries, but in the simple case where you have good control over how sys.stdout out is used through your framework this can be a reasonable approach.

```
sys.stdout = io.open(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Thank you! Only this answer worked for me. Python 3.10.5. OS: Windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

First: `reload(sys)` and setting some random default encoding just regarding the need of an output terminal stream is bad practice. `reload` often changes things in sys which have been put in place depending on the environment - e.g.  sys.stdin/stdout streams, sys.excepthook, etc.

### Solving the encode problem on stdout

The best solution I know for solving the encode problem of `print`'ing unicode strings and beyond-ascii `str`'s (e.g. from literals) on sys.stdout is: to take care of a sys.stdout (file-like object) which is capable and optionally tolerant regarding the needs:

- When `sys.stdout.encoding` is `None` for some reason, or non-existing, or erroneously false or "less" than what the stdout terminal or stream really is capable of, then try to provide a correct `.encoding` attribute. At last by replacing `sys.stdout & sys.stderr` by a translating file-like object.
- When the terminal / stream still cannot encode all occurring unicode chars, and when you don't want to break `print`'s just because of that, you can introduce an encode-with-replace behavior in the translating file-like object.

Here an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import sys

class SmartStdout:
    def __init__(self, encoding=None, org_stdout=None):
        if org_stdout is None:
            org_stdout = getattr(sys.stdout, 'org_stdout', sys.stdout)
        self.org_stdout = org_stdout
        self.encoding = encoding or \
                        getattr(org_stdout, 'encoding', None) or 'utf-8'
    def write(self, s):
        self.org_stdout.write(s.encode(self.encoding, 'backslashreplace'))
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.org_stdout, name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.stdout.isatty():
        sys.stdout = sys.stderr = SmartStdout()

    us = u'aouäöüфżß²'
    print us
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

### Using beyond-ascii plain string literals in Python 2 / 2 + 3 code

The only good reason to change the global default encoding (to UTF-8 only) I think is regarding an application **source code** decision - and not because of I/O stream encodings issues: For writing beyond-ascii string literals into code without being forced to always use `u'string'` style unicode escaping. This can be done rather consistently (despite what *anonbadger*'s article says) by taking care of a Python 2 or Python 2 + 3 source code basis which uses ascii or UTF-8 plain string literals consistently - as far as those strings potentially undergo silent unicode conversion and move between modules or potentially go to stdout. For that, prefer "`# encoding: utf-8`" or ascii (no declaration). Change or drop libraries which still rely in a very dumb way fatally on ascii default encoding errors beyond chr #127 (which is rare today).

And do like this at application start (and/or via sitecustomize.py) in addition to the `SmartStdout` scheme above - without using `reload(sys)`:

```
...
def set_defaultencoding_globally(encoding='utf-8'):
    assert sys.getdefaultencoding() in ('ascii', 'mbcs', encoding)
    import imp
    _sys_org = imp.load_dynamic('_sys_org', 'sys')
    _sys_org.setdefaultencoding(encoding)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr = SmartStdout()
    set_defaultencoding_globally('utf-8') 
    s = 'aouäöüфżß²'
    print s
```

This way string literals and most operations (except character iteration) work comfortable without thinking about unicode conversion as if there would be Python3 only. 
File I/O of course always need special care regarding encodings - as it is in Python3.

Note: plains strings then are implicitely converted from utf-8 to unicode in `SmartStdout` before being converted to the output stream enconding.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick hack for anyone who is (1) On a Windows platform (2) running Python 2.7 and (3) annoyed because a nice piece of software (i.e., not written by you so not immediately a candidate for encode/decode printing maneuvers) won't display the "pretty unicode characters" in the IDLE environment (Pythonwin prints unicode fine), For example, the neat First Order Logic symbols that Stephan Boyer uses in the output from his pedagogic prover at [First Order Logic Prover](https://github.com/stepchowfun/theorem-prover).

I didn't like the idea of forcing a sys reload and I couldn't get the system to cooperate with setting environment variables like PYTHONIOENCODING (tried direct Windows environment variable and also dropping that in a sitecustomize.py in site-packages as a one liner ='utf-8').

So, if you are willing to hack your way to success, go to your IDLE directory, typically:
"C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib"
Locate the file IOBinding.py. Make a copy of that file and store it somewhere else so you can revert to original behavior when you choose. Open the file in the idlelib with an editor (e.g., IDLE). Go to this code area:

```
# Encoding for file names
filesystemencoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding()

encoding = "ascii"
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    # On Windows, we could use "mbcs". However, to give the user
    # a portable encoding name, we need to find the code page 
    try:
        # --> 6/5/17 hack to force IDLE to display utf-8 rather than cp1252
        # --> encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
        encoding = 'utf-8'
        codecs.lookup(encoding)
    except LookupError:
        pass
```

In other words, comment out the original code line following the '*try*' that was making the encoding variable equal to *locale.getdefaultlocale* (because that will give you cp1252 which you don't want) and instead brute force it to 'utf-8' (by adding the line '*encoding = 'utf-8*' as shown).

I believe this only affects IDLE display to stdout and not the encoding used for file names etc. (that is obtained in the filesystemencoding prior). If you have a problem with any other code you run in IDLE later, just replace the IOBinding.py file with the original unmodified file.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the encoding of your entire operating system. [On Ubuntu you can do this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue) with

```
sudo apt install locales 
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8    
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Answer (score 1):

windows set environment variable
`PYTHONUTF8=1`

Answer (score 0):

set default encoding of OS to be `UTF-8`.
Eg., on ubuntu edit file `/etc/default/locale` and set:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want stable `UTF-8` support on file `read`/`write` without same declarations everywhere, here are two solutions:

**1. Patch `io` module at runtime (danger operation at your own risk)**

```
import pathlib as pathlib
import tempfile

import chardet


def patchIOWithUtf8Default():
    import builtins
    import importlib.util
    import sys
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec("io")
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    exec(compile(spec.loader.get_source(spec.name) + """
    def open(*args, **kwargs):
        args = list(args)
        mode = kwargs.get('mode', (args + [''])[1])
        if (len(args) < 4 and 'b' not in mode) or 'encoding' in kwargs:
            kwargs['encoding'] = 'utf8'
        elif len(args) >= 4 and args[3] is None:
            args[3] = 'utf8'
        return _io.open(*args, **kwargs)
    """, module.__spec__.origin, "exec"), module.__dict__)
    sys.modules[module.__name__] = module
    builtins.open = __import__("io").open
    importlib.reload(importlib.import_module("pathlib"))


def main():
    patchIOWithUtf8Default()
    filename = tempfile.mktemp()
    text = "Common\n常\nSense\n识\n天地玄黄"
    print("Original text:", repr(text))
    pathlib.Path(filename).write_text(text)
    encoding = chardet.detect(open(filename, mode="rb").read())["encoding"]
    print("Written encoding by pathlib:", encoding)
    print("Written text by pathlib:", repr(open(filename, newline="", encoding=encoding).read()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sample output:

```
Original text: 'Common\n常\nSense\n识\n天地玄黄'
Written encoding by pathlib: utf-8
Written text by pathlib: 'Common\r\n常\r\nSense\r\n识\r\n天地玄黄'
```

**2. Use 3rd library as pathlib wrapper**

https://github.com/baijifeilong/IceSpringPathLib

`pip install IceSpringPathLib`

```
import pathlib
import tempfile

import chardet

import IceSpringPathLib

tempfile.mktemp()
filename = tempfile.mktemp()
text = "Common\n常\nSense\n识\n天地玄黄"
print("Original text:", repr(text))

pathlib.Path(filename).write_text(text)
encoding = chardet.detect(open(filename, mode="rb").read())["encoding"]
print("\nWritten text by pathlib:", repr(open(filename, newline="", encoding=encoding).read()))
print("Written encoding by pathlib:", encoding)

IceSpringPathLib.Path(filename).write_text(text)
encoding = chardet.detect(open(filename, mode="rb").read())["encoding"]
print("\nWritten text by IceSpringPathLib:", repr(open(filename, newline="", encoding=encoding).read()))
print("Written encoding by IceSpringPathLib:", encoding)
```

Sample output:

```
Original text: 'Common\n常\nSense\n识\n天地玄黄'

Written text by pathlib: 'Common\r\n常\r\nSense\r\n识\r\n天地玄黄'
Written encoding by pathlib: GB2312

Written text by IceSpringPathLib: 'Common\n常\nSense\n识\n天地玄黄'
Written encoding by IceSpringPathLib: utf-8
```

Answer (score -1):

This fixed the issue for me.

```
import os
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"
```

Comment: Did not for me. But worked when exported the variable in the shell before entering python, or used reload(sys); sys.defaultencoding("utf-8").