# XLRDError when reading xls files

Tags: python, encoding, xlrd

I tried reading excel files by the following code:

```
import os
import xlrd

files = os.listdir(".")[1:101]


for file in files:
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
```

but I got an error message like this.

> XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n'

So I tried opening the files one by one.

And I found files named like this are readable,
"**14.08.01-08.07.xlsx.xlsx**"
but files named like this format are not readable. "**14.08.22-08.28.xlsx.xls**"

So I opened the files and found that files with extension "**xlsx.xls**" have problem with encoding.

These files include Korean characters, so I tried opening them by changing encoding into utf-8, in vain.

In conclusion I think I cannot read **xlsx.xls** files because of the encoding problem.

Is there anyway to solve this sort of problem?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511743/using-xlrd-to-read-excel-xls-file-containing-chinese-and-or-hindi-characters) helps?

Comment: Are they `xls` or `xlsx` format  - strange file extension naming going on there...

Answer (score 1):

Try `xlrd.open_workbook(file, encoding_override="utf-8")`