# Save unicode in redis but fetch error

Tags: python, redis

I'm using mongodb and redis, redis is my cache.

I'm caching mongodb objects with redis-py:

```
obj in mongodb: {u'name': u'match', u'section_title': u'\u6d3b\u52a8', u'title': 
u'\u6bd4\u8d5b', u'section_id': 1, u'_id': ObjectId('4fb1ed859b10ed2041000001'), u'id': 1}
```

the obj fetched from redis with hgetall(key, obj) is:

```
{'name': 'match', 'title': '\xe6\xaf\x94\xe8\xb5\x9b', 'section_title': 
'\xe6\xb4\xbb\xe5\x8a\xa8', 'section_id': '1', '_id': '4fb1ed859b10ed2041000001', 'id': '1'}
```

As you can see, obj fetched from cache is str instead of unicode, so in my app, there is error s like :'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

Can anyone give some suggestions? thank u

Comment: And how you save mongodb objects in redis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update*, for global setting, check [jmoz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12285706/165603).

If you're using third-party lib such as `django-redis`, you may need to specify a customized `ConnectionFactory`:

```
class DecodeConnectionFactory(redis_cache.pool.ConnectionFactory):
    def get_connection(self, params):
        params['decode_responses'] = True
        return super(DecodeConnectionFactory, self).get_connection(self, params)
```

---

Assuming you're using redis-py, you'd better to pass `str` instead of `unicode` to Redis, or else [Redis will encode it automatically](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/connection.py#L282) for `*set` commands, normally [in UTF-8](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/connection.py#L165). For the `*get` commands, Redis has no idea about the formal type of a value and has to just return the value in `str` directly.

Thus, As Denis said, the way that you storing the object to Redis is critical. You need to transform the value to `str` to make the Redis layer transparent for you.

Also, [set the default encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105441/how-to-set-default-encoding-in-pythonsetdefaultencoding-function-does-not-exist) instead of using `ascii`

Comment: Why would they auto encode it but then just leave you a string on get?

Comment: @jmoz I'm not sure, maybe the author knows the reason =p .But unlike adapter such as psycopg2, normally the redis-py client does not store the original datatype w/ the data. Thus there is no way to know exactly what type the data(string) is originally and how to decode it. Maybe insisting on `str` instead of accepting other types of value then converting them to `str` implicitly, is better, but who knows.

Comment: @okm I found something the other day regarding this, check my answer.

Comment: I enabled this setting and it seems that I now get `UnicodeDecodeError` when trying to store and retrieve a dictionary in Django's cache

Answer (score 28):

I think I've discovered the problem.  After reading this, I had to explicitly decode from redis which is a pain, but works.

I stumbled across a blog post where the author's output was all unicode strings which was obv different to mine.

Looking into the `StrictRedis.__init__` there is a parameter `decode_responses` which by default is `False`. https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/273a47e299a499ed0053b8b90966dc2124504983/redis/client.py#L446

Pass in `decode_responses=True` on construct and for me this FIXES THE OP'S ISSUE.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try later. This maybe the best solution as I won't mess up my code.

Answer (score 6):

for each string you can use the `decode` function to transform it in utf-8, e.g. for the value if the title field in your code:

```
In [7]: a='\xe6\xaf\x94\xe8\xb5\x9b'

In [8]: a.decode('utf8')
Out[8]: u'\u6bd4\u8d5b'
```

Comment: Man I think hi is want make cache not for decode-encode fun, but for increase him system.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you always encode to utf-8 before writing to MongoDB or Redis (or any external system). And that you decode('utf-8') when you fecth results, so that you always work with Unicode in Python.