# Why is my defaultencoding ‘utf-8’ with python 2.7.2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python, the defaultencoding is stored in 'unicode_default_encoding', and I find out all Python source code, there are 2 functions with it.

1. `_PyUnicode_Init() //strcpy(unicode_default_encoding, "ascii");`
2. `setencoding()` in site.py

So nobody modifies the defaultencoding. Then why is my defaultencoding 'utf-8'?

Comment: Do you have the file `lib/site-packages/sitecustomize.py` in your python install folder or is the file `sitecustomize.py` anywhere in the python search path? It's used to change the default encoding. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7105835/637284

Comment: Are you're using Eclipse? Eclipse Pydev IDE, default character encoding is set to utf-8. So it might be a matter of environment. Some dev tools changes defaults to make it "better" for the user.

Comment: There's no sitecustomize.py in my python and I just run python in shell without any IDE

Answer (score 0):

Looks the settings in site.py will affect the default encoding.

Check out http://blog.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html

> Edit site.py (in the standard library) directly. Seems like a bad idea. Though maybe I'll just delete the del sys.setdefaultencoding line... anyway, site.py might appear in other places on your computer as well (e.g., /etc/pythonX.Y/site.py).