# How to stop Django template render_to_string from trying to encode unicode to ascii?

Tags: django, encoding, django-models, django-templates, ascii

I have a model, "Event", with the following attribute:

```
desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

When an instance of the model is saved, it seems to convert special characters to unicode, for example a left double quotation mark becomes "\u201c". Later on, I reference {{ event.desc }} in a template (which works fine), but when I render the template to a string, I get a "UnicodeEncodeError". For context, I am trying to render a simple bit of HTML to a string for posting to an API.

How I render the template:

```
description = render_to_string('event_description.html', {'event': self})
```

and the resulting error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 845: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to prevent render_to_string from encoding to ascii, or some more appropriate way to prevent this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like there is a `.encode()` somewhere which tried to encode the `u'\u201c'` to ascii and failed.
You could either check the traceback to locate the line and change it to explicit `.encode('utf8')`.
Or change the default encoding of your Python system to 'utf-8': ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105441/how-to-set-default-encoding-in-python-setdefaultencoding-function-does-not-ex) & [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try using in your view:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Regards,

Comment: That won't solve the problem. This sets the encoding for the python source code, and does not affect the template at all.

Answer (score 0):

That very same problem just happened to me; I was getting this error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf5' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
(...)
Error during template rendering
(...)
<h1 id="site-name">{{ servidor }}</h1>
```

In my case, which may or may not be the same as yours (there aren't enough details on the question to be certain of that), was that ´servidor´ was an object; Django was trying to implcitly convert it to a string, but using the wrong encoding; this was solved by creating a new parameter to the context named ´nome_servidor´, and explicitly encoding it beforehand:

```
context = {
    'nome_servidor': unicode(servidor),
    'servidor': servidor,
    'logs' : servidor.lista_logs()  
}
```

And then changing the template to explicitly use the encoded string:

```
<h1 id="site-name">{{ nome_servidor }}</h1>
```