# UnicodeEncode Error in deployed Python Application

Tags: python, eclipse, sqlite, python-2.7, unicode

I have a simple python/pyqt application that is inserting data into a SQLITE database table,
some of the entries contain special characters such as umlauts. 
I did the development using eclipse, tested it and managed to insert all the data without any errors.
I then decided to create an executable, of my application. I am using py2exe to create the executable. My setup.py looks as follows

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import os
includes=["sqlite3","sip","PyQt4", "PyQt4.QtGui"]
excludes=[]
packages=[]
dll_excludes=['libgdk-win32-1.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll', 'tk84.dll']

setup(

      options={"py2exe": {"compressed": 2,
                          "optimize": 2,
                          "includes": includes,
                          "excludes": excludes,
                          "packages": packages,
                          "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                          "bundle_files": 2,
                          "dist_dir": "dist",
                          "xref": False,
                          "skip_archive": False,
                          "ascii": False,
                          "custom_boot_script": '',
                          }
               },
      windows=['MainWindow.py'],     
      )
```

It seems to work in as far as I get an executable application in a "dist" folder, when I run it, it loads fine, When I insert the same data, it falls over at the special characters(umlauts). of 100 entries I successfully insert 60, the first occurrence of an accented character causes the executable to fall over with the error message

> (, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii',
>   u'Citro\xebnCX', 5, 6, 'ordinal not in range(128)'), )

Just so happens I was inserting CitroenCX into the table, the 'e' being the french accented character

I don't know why when I run the python/pyqt application from my eclipse environment, I get no errors, but once I create an executable i get this error.

What changes should I make in my setup file

---

Thanks. I applied the solution

```
 def setencoding():
    encoding = "ascii" 
    if 0:
        import locale
        loc = locale.getdefaultlocale()
        if loc[1]:
            encoding = loc[1]
    if 0: #changes comes here, change 0 to 1
        encoding = "undefined" #the encoding you want
    if encoding != "ascii":
        sys.setdefaultencoding(encoding)
```

and it worked for me. Not an original solution, saw it on SO [How to set default encoding in Python (setdefaultencoding() function does not exist)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105441/how-to-set-default-encoding-in-python-setdefaultencoding-function-does-not-ex)

Comment: to exclude `py2exe` from the equation, you could try to run `python MainWindow.py` in a console and compare it with `python MainWindow.py >output`. The former might succeed while the latter should fail.

Comment: modifying by hand predefined `setencoding()` function in a system-wide `site.py` is a terrrible terrible idea. It changes how all python scripts work on your system in a such way that *only occasionally* would break them. Many scripts won't expect your changes. It would be a nightmare to troubleshoot random breakage in programs that you even didn't know they were implemented in Python. Don't do it. Fix your code instead. If you don't know how, [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the default encoding selected by the different environments. Any I/O of Unicode to stdin or stdout will trigger an encode or decode using the default encoding. If that encoding is `'ascii'` then any accented character will fail.

You can check the defaults to be sure:

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
sys.stdin.encoding
sys.stdout.encoding
```

Comment: Thanks. your response got me on the right track. I eventually looked at 
How to set default encoding in Python (setdefaultencoding() function does not exist)? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105441/how-to-set-default-encoding-in-python-setdefaultencoding-function-does-not-ex