# Is there a way to change the default encoding for all run configurations within Pydev?

Tags: unicode, encoding, pydev

There has been some discussion of the [merits](http://blog.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html) or [demerits](http://opensourcehacker.com/2010/01/24/aptana-studio-eclipse-pydev-default-unicode-encoding/)/[evilness](http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/syssetdefaultencoding-is-evil/) of using sys.setdefaultencoding(...) in python 2.x I'm using PyDev and I want to have the default 'out of the box' python behaviour (US-ASCII as default (non-)encoding), as I feel this is safer (I don't like the site_customize.py approach), even if more laborious.

When I'm using PyDev (particularly for running unittests) it be defaults calls sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF-8'). Other answers have recommended changing the encoding setting to 'US-ASCII' in each 'run configurations' Common tab.

I would like to change the **default** for all run configurations to 'US-ASCII' across pydev (per workspace) or at least globally for one Python interpreter. Is there a way to do this?

Having looked into the implementation: Pydev uses a PYDEV_CONSOLE_ENCODING environment variable to get the encoding (this is within the site_customize.py file in the org.python.pydev plugin). However this *seems* to be set from the setting of the run-dialog in the Run configurations drop down. The default says "inherited - UTF-8" but I haven't found anywhere to change this in pydev's settings. I've tried setting the environment variable PYDEV_CONSOLE_ENCODING in various places, but this hasn't got through to site_customize.py (instead it reads the value from the Encoding setting on the dialog tab).

Comment: Why in the world would you want to go back to ASCII as the default?

Comment: @tchrist Ummm why don't you look at the two references I gave http://opensourcehacker.com/2010/01/24/aptana-studio-eclipse-pydev-default-unicode-encoding http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/syssetdefaultencoding-is-evil/

Comment: I filed another ticket for this issue: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/315

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the default encoding at window > preferences > general > workspace > text file encoding (set it to other > us-ascii).

Comment: unexpected that text-file encoding sets the default for consoles, but great... Maybe one for the pydev docs? I (like others before me) have had loads of head-scratching trying because I couldn't reproduce certain unicode-based errors within Aptana - lightbulb moment came when running unittests in console gave an different result to the same tests run within Aptana.