# Why is sys.getdefaultencoding() different from sys.stdout.encoding and how does this break Unicode strings?

Tags: python, stdout, utf, sys

I spent a few angry hours looking for the problem with Unicode strings that was broken down to something that Python (2.7) hides from me and I still don't understand. First, I tried to use `u".."` strings consistently in my code, but that resulted in the infamous `UnicodeEncodeError`. I tried using `.encode('utf8')`, but that didn't help either. Finally, it turned out I shouldn't use either and it all works out automagically. However, I (here I need to give credit to a friend who helped me) did notice something weird while banging my head against the wall. `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns *ascii*, while `sys.stdout.encoding` returns *UTF-8*. 1. in the code below works fine without any modifications to `sys` and 2. raises a `UnicodeEncodeError`. If I change the default system encoding with  `reload(sys).setdefaultencoding("utf8")`, then 2. works fine. My question is why the two encoding variables are different in the first place and how do I manage to use the wrong encoding in this simple piece of code? Please, don't send me to the [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), I've read that obviously in the tens of questions about `UnicodeEncodeError`.

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys


class Token:
    def __init__(self, string, final=False):
        self.value = string
        self.final = final

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value

print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
print(sys.stdout.encoding)

# 1.
myString = "I need 20 000€."
tok = Token(myString)
print(tok)

reload(sys).setdefaultencoding("utf8")

# 2.
myString = u"I need 20 000€."
tok = Token(myString)
print(tok)
```

Comment: My question is not about a solution to a problem, but about its reasons. I know how to solve it and I know it doesn't exist in Python 3.0. What you're asking is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is why the two encoding variables are different in the first place

They serve different purposes.

`sys.stdout.encoding` should be the encoding that your terminal uses to interpret text otherwise you may get mojibake in the output. It may be utf-8 in one environment, cp437 in another, etc.

`sys.getdefaultencoding()` is used on Python 2 for implicit conversions (when the encoding is not set explicitly) i.e., Python 2 may mix ascii-only bytestrings and Unicode strings together e.g., `xml.etree.ElementTree` stores text in ascii range as bytestrings or [`json.dumps()` returns an ascii-only bytestring instead of Unicode in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32539609/4279) — perhaps due to performance — bytes were cheaper than Unicode for representing ascii characters. Implicit conversions are forbidden in Python 3.

`sys.getdefaultencoding()` is always `'ascii'` on all systems in Python 2 unless you override it that you should not do otherwise it may hide bugs and your data may be easily corrupted due to the implicit conversions using a possibly wrong encoding for the data.

btw, there is another common encoding `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` that may be different from the two. `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` should be the encoding that is used to encode OS data (filenames, command-line arguments, environment variables).

The source code encoding declared using `#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` may be different from all of the already-mentioned encodings.

Naturally, if you read data from a file, network; it may use character encodings different from the above e.g., if a file created in notepad is saved using Windows ANSI encoding such as `cp1252` then on another system all the standard encodings can be different from it.

The point being: there could be ***multiple*** encodings for reasons unrelated to Python and to avoid the headache, use Unicode to represent text: convert as soon as possible encoded text to Unicode on input, and encode it to bytes (possibly using a different encoding) as late as possible on output — this is so called the concept of [Unicode sandwich](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html).

> how do I manage to use the wrong encoding in this simple piece of code?

1. Your first code example is not fine. You use non-ascii literal characters in a byte string on Python 2 that you should not do. Use bytestrings' literals only for binary data (or so called native strings if necessary). The code may produce mojibake such as `I need 20 000Γé¼.` (notice the character noise) if you run it using Python 2 in any environment that does not use utf-8-compatible encoding such as Windows console
2. The second code example is ok assuming `reload(sys)` is not part of it. If you don't want to prefix all string literals with `u''`; you could use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

Your actual issue is `UnicodeEncodeError` error and `reload(sys)` is not the right solution!
The correct solution is to [configure your locale properly on POSIX (`LANG`, `LC_CTYPE`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33060935/4279) or [set `PYTHONIOENCODING` envvar if the output is redirected to a pipe/file or install `win-unicode-console` to print Unicode to Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/4279).

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed the same behaviour of some standard code (mailman library).
Thanks for your analysis, it helped me save some time. :-)
The problem is exactly the same. My system uses `sys.getdefaultencoding()` and gets `ascii`, which is inappropriate to handle a list of 1000 UTF-8 encoded names.

There is a mismatch between stdin/stdout and even filesystem encoding (utf-8) on one hand and "defaultencoding" on the other (ascii). This thread: [How to print UTF-8 encoded text to the console in Python < 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741574/how-to-set-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-in-python) seems to indicate that it is well known and [Changing default encoding of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python) contains some indication that a more homogeneous (like "`utf-8` everywhere") would break other things like the hash implementation.

For that reason it is also not straightforward to change the defaultencoding. (See http://blog.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html for various ways to do so.) It is removed from the `sys` instance in the `site.py` file.