# Can't print Unicode Bitcoin symbol in Python 2

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to print the Unicode Bitcoin symbol `\u2043` in Python 2.  I have tried adding `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.

```
$ python2 -c 'print u'\u0243''
```

Raises `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0243' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`.  However, doing this from the Python shell works.

```
$ python2
>>> print u'\u0243'
Ƀ
```

Why isn't this code working?

```
bitcoin = u'\u0243'
quote = u'{:,.2f}'.format(float(val), '.2f')
print bitcoin, quote
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that your terminal encoding is ascii, and that `\u0243` can't be encoded to ascii. Perhaps setting the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to e.g. `utf-8` would help..

Comment: I am using Konsole in KDE, and rightl clicking on it I can see the UTF-8 selected when looking at the Encoding. Is this more of a bash issue? 
http://joelhy.github.io/img/konsole_select_encoding.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.. I'm on windows, and there unicode and the console has never been friends..

Comment: Thanks @thebjorn that worked. I thought I had that setup but missread the envvar to PYTHONENCODING instead of PYTHON**IO**ENCODING.

Comment: It also worked by adding bitcoin= u'u\0243'.encoding('utf-8') at the end of the variable.

Comment: Unicode added the standard Bitcoin symbol ₿ in 2017 as U+20BF; in Python it is \u20bf

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, if `sys.stdout.isatty()` returns `True` but `sys.stdout.encoding` is `'ANSI_X3.4-1968'` (ascii) then you should configure your locale (check `LANG`, `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_ALL` envvars) to use non-ascii encoding if you need to print non-ascii characters.

If `sys.stdout.isatty()` is false then configure `PYTHONIOENCODING` envvar outside your script.
Always print Unicode, don't hardcode the character encoding of your environment inside your script.