# Getting Invalid Hook Procedure error after injected dll in windows hook

Tags: python, windows, winapi, hook, ctypes

I am trying to hook into windows globally by injecting a dll.
My code works with python2.7, but sadly fails, when using Python3.7 with the already mentioned error.
Here is an example code:

```
user32.SetWindowsHookExA.errcheck = errcheck_bool
user32.SetWindowsHookExA.restype = HHOOK
user32.SetWindowsHookExA.argtypes = (c_int,     # _In_ idHook
                                     HOOKPROC,  # _In_ lpfn
                                     HINSTANCE, # _In_ hMod
                                     DWORD)     # _In_ dwThreadId

user32.CallNextHookEx.restype = LRESULT
user32.CallNextHookEx.argtypes = (HHOOK,  # _In_opt_ hhk
                                  c_int,  # _In_     nCode
                                  WPARAM, # _In_     wParam
                                  LPARAM) # _In_     lParam

user32.GetMessageW.argtypes = (LPMSG, # _Out_    lpMsg
                               HWND,  # _In_opt_ hWnd
                               UINT,  # _In_     wMsgFilterMin
                               UINT)  # _In_     wMsgFilterMax

user32.TranslateMessage.argtypes = (LPMSG,)
user32.DispatchMessageW.argtypes = (LPMSG,)

GetModuleHandle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA
GetModuleHandle.restype = POINTER(c_void_p)

LoadLibrary = ctypes.windll.kernel32.LoadLibraryA
LoadLibrary.restype = HINSTANCE

GetProcAddress = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress
GetProcAddress.restype = HOOKPROC

user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId.restype = DWORD

def pointer_msg_loop():
    lib = LoadLibrary(r'C:\Users\Braun\Documents\BA_Thesis\ba-oliver-braun-logging-tool-code\MessagesDll\x64\Release\Dll.dll')
    handle = GetModuleHandle(r'C:\Users\Braun\Documents\BA_Thesis\ba-oliver-braun-logging-tool-code\MessagesDll\x64\Release\Dll.dll')
    print(lib)
    print(handle)
    procedure = GetProcAddress(handle, "meconnect".encode())
    print(procedure)
    print('correct value procedure')
    tHook = user32.SetWindowsHookExA(WH_GETMESSAGE, procedure, lib, 0)
    time.sleep(30)
    user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(tHook)
    print(tHook)
    msg = MSG()
    while True:
        bRet = user32.GetMessageW(byref(msg), None, 0, 0)
        if not bRet:
            break
        if bRet == -1:
            raise WinError(get_last_error())
        user32.TranslateMessage(byref(msg))
        user32.DispatchMessageW(byref(msg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    import datetime
    import threading
    control_key_pressed = False
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    tmouse = threading.Thread(target=mouse_msg_loop)
    tkeyboard = threading.Thread(target=keyboard_msg_loop)
    ttouch = threading.Thread(target=pointer_msg_loop)
    tmouse.start()
    tkeyboard.start()
    ttouch.start()
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            user32.PostThreadMessageW(tmouse.ident, WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
            break
```

DLL:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#pragma data_seg("Shared")
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker,"/section:Shared,rws")

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

HHOOK tHook;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT meconnect(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    BOOL EnableMouseInPointer = TRUE;
    if (code == HC_ACTION) {
        LPMSG data = (LPMSG)lParam;
        if (data->message == WM_POINTERDOWN) {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "eee", NULL, 0);
        }
    }
    return(CallNextHookEx(tHook, code, wParam, lParam));
}
```

Some interesting observations: When changing LoadLibraryA to LoadLibraryW even python2.7 fails.
This seems really obvious and i suspect its because of maybe the different string types that both versions enforce? But yeah what can i change to make it work in Python3.7

Comment: You'd better call `SetWindowsHookEx` in the DLL, the `tHook` in the DLL is not defined which will cause the undefined behavior in calling `CallNextHookEx`.

Comment: Hey, do you mind answering another question. I currently have data in my callback function containing message information. i would like to transfer this to my python file with zmq. do you know how to achieve this so i get the message data at the time its happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3.7, the result of `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is `'utf-8'`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33726891/10611792) from @jfs metioned that

> `sys.getdefaultencoding()` always runs 'ascii' on all systems of
>   Python 2, unless you rewrite it.

This may be why you got it wrong.

1. use `b''` instead of `r''`, or just use Wide-byte function.
2. `GetProcAddress` has no Wide-byte version. Just use `GetProcAddress(handle, b'meconnect')` as well.
3. `tHook` in DLL is not defined, and it will cause undefined behavior in next hook.
4. You'd better put the message loop before `UnhookWindowsHookEx` and instead of the `sleep` method.

You can call `SetWindowsHookEx` in the DLL. Here is the sample.
DLL:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
HHOOK tHook;
HMODULE hinstDLL;
LRESULT CALLBACK meconnect(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    BOOL EnableMouseInPointer = TRUE;
    if (code == HC_ACTION) {
        LPMSG data = (LPMSG)lParam;
        if (data->message == WM_POINTERDOWN) {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "eee", NULL, 0);
        }
    }
    return(CallNextHookEx(tHook, code, wParam, lParam));
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL SetHook()
{
    tHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, meconnect, hinstDLL, 0);

    if (tHook == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    else
        return TRUE;
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL UnHook()
{
    return UnhookWindowsHookEx(tHook);
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        hinstDLL = hModule;
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

python:

```
import threading
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
from ctypes import *
import win32api
import win32gui
def pointer_msg_loop():
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(r'PATH\DLL.dll')
    print(lib)
    res = lib.SetHook()
    print(res)
    win32gui.PumpMessages()
    res = lib.UnHook()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ttouch = threading.Thread(target=pointer_msg_loop)
    ttouch.start()
    ttouch.join()
```

Comment: Omg it worked! Thank you so much. I am still wondering why moving it to the dll fixed it and why it didnt matter for 2.7

Comment: @oli: That's a [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks#hook-procedures) requirement: *"A global hook procedure can be called in the context of any application in the same desktop as the calling thread, so **the procedure must be in a separate DLL module**."*

Comment: Ok that makes sense, its just weird how this for some reason is such a big difference between the pythons.