# Why i can't change my python default encoding?

Tags: python, default

```
nano  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py

import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF-8')
```

after i finished ,

```
root@debian:/home/debian# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.getdefaultencoding()
ascii
```

What is the matter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read following:

1. [Why should we NOT use sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") in a py script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3828723/)
2. [How to print UTF-8 encoded text to the console in Python < 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11741574/)

I recommend using `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to top of your `.py` file.