# unicode string tolerance in Eclipse+PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, unicode, pydev

I'm using **Eclipse+PyDev** to write code and often face unicode issues when moving this code to production. The reason is shown in this little example

```
a = u'фыва '\
'фыва'
```

If Eclipse see this it creates unicode string like nothing happened, but if type same command directly to Python shell(Python 2.7.3) you'll get this:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

because correct code is:

```
a = u'фыва '\
u'фыва'
```

But because of **Eclipse+PyDev**'s "tolerance" I always get in trouble :( How can I force PyDev to "follow the rules"?

Comment: check that `sys.version` is Python 2.x and `sys.defaultencoding()` is 'ascii' when you run your scripts from PyDev. Check whether PyDev changes sitecustomize, usercustomize modules. If it runs the scripts interactively; check where PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable points

Comment: @j-f-sebastian, `sys.version` 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3], sys.defaultencoding() -- no such funstion.

Comment: sys.getdefaultencoding()

Comment: @j-f-sebastian, you are right. default encoding in shell is 'ascii' and in PyDev is 'UTF-8'. How can I change this in Eclipse?

Comment: I changed encoding to US-ASCII, but this doesn't helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the encoding for the console is utf-8.

There's currently no way to set that globally in the UI, although you can change it by editing: `\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.6\pysrc\pydev_sitecustomize\sitecustomize.py`

And just remove the call to: (line 108) sys.setdefaultencoding(encoding)

Answer (score 2):

This issue should be fixed in PyDev 3.4.0 (not released yet). Fabio (PyDev maintainer) says: *"from now on PyDev will only set the PYTHONIOENCODING and will no longer change the default encoding"*. And `PYTHONIOENCODING` is supported since Python 2.6.

Here is the [commit on GitHub](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/0ee184c4456145b391f68137da2f71637fc06443).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as the first line of your source files. It should make Python behave.

Comment: Do you get this error for string literals in your own code or for data from outside sources? F.ex. for data read from file, received from web form or database.

Comment: there is no outside sources and there is no error. The problem is in absence of this error!

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me in my source code without having to modify the pydev sitecustomize.py file:

```
import sys
reload(sys).setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

You could use "ascii" or whatever other encoding you wanted to use.

In my case, the when I ran the program on the command-line, PyDev was using "utf-8", whereas the console was incorrectly setting "ascii".

Comment: Thanks but I decide to switch to PyCharm and I don't have this problem anymore

Answer (score 0):

It may not be what you are asking. But for my case I got these UTF-8 characters by accident copying my code from various sources. To find what character is making troubles I did in my **Eclipse Mars**:

```
Edit->set encoding
other->US ASCII
```

then I tried  to save my file. And I got modal window telling me "Save problems". There was button `"Select First Character"`
It showed me troubling character and I just deleted that character and typed  ASCII one.