# Flask code raises UnicodeDecodeError (only) when ran from outside Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, utf-8, flask, pydev

I am using Apache2 with mod_wsgi to deploy a Flask application.

When ran from Eclipse with pydev (i.e. using the "run" menu icon in Eclipse), this application works perfectly.

But when the exact same code is ran from outside Eclipse - either by calling the script from the command line, or through mod_wsgi - a `UnicodeDecodeError` is raised and the page can't be displayed.

Here is the (shortened) piece of problematic code :

```
label = 'créer'
row = '<tr><td>{cell_label}</td></tr>'.format(cell_label = label)
render_template('template.html', row = row)
```

template.html contains :

```
<table>
    {{ row | safe }}
</table>
```

and the error raised is :

```
'<tr><td>{cell_label}</td></tr>'.format(cell_label = label)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\\xe9' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**other information**

- `echo $LANG` returns :

  en_US.UTF-8
- `file flask_app.py returns`

  Python script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable
- I use the same interpreter (python 2.7.3 in a virtualenv) when I run the code from Ecplise and when conduction my tests.

**EDIT**

Changed question title and description that reflect the fact than the code can only be ran through Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in two other answered questions :

**identifying the problem**

([unicode string tolerance in Eclipse+PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359101/unicode-string-tolerance-in-eclipsepydev))

Basically, what goes wrong is that Pydev changes python's default encoding in the background. Which means that code containing non-ASCII characters that works just fine when ran through Eclipse with Pydev might just crash in any other context.

**Finding a solution**

([How to print UTF-8 encoded text to the console in Python < 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741574/how-to-set-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-in-pytho))

The default encoding should not be changed. Keith's answer gives a workaround, but it really shouldn't be used. The only good solution is to realize that Pydev's environment is nonstandart and juste rewrite chunks of code.