# Python coding utf-8 default

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

Isn't it possible to tell your python interpreter to consider by default all .py files as encoded in utf-8??

While this is not good for portability as you may then forget to place the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` kind of headers,

it is today a pain for me to have to always have to remember to write this header when writing short temporary scripts with unicode strings inside.

(for example when working on remote envs, I don't use a full-bundled-and-configured editor which could systematically add the header for me, so I have to remember that detail)

Answer (score 3):

You can do a few tricks, but none are that great IMO. The "solution" is to move to Python 3.

When you initialize your shell/python, you can do this hack which is not 100% full-proof:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 -S

import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
import site
```

This trick is not such a great idea, but maybe should meet your needs for remote shells and such to test things quickly.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741574/how-to-set-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python) for more info and discussion of the drawbacks. (Possible duplicates).