# Why is python converting Kurdich characters into UTF-8 literals?

Tags: python, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I was trying to take the content of a text file and map it into a json file, but I noticed that python automatically turned the kurdish(sorani) text into UTF-8 literals. Can someone explain why python does this and how can I prevent the conversion?

You can test it with the code below:

```
def readText():
    # test.txt contains kurdish sorani characters (an article)
    # Sorani example: ڕۆژتان باش بەڕێزان. من ناوم ڕەنجە. 
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as context:
        data = context.readlines()
        return data
print(readText())
```

I'm running python 2.x on Ubuntu 14.x. Python2.x does this! Python 3.x does not convert it and works just fine.

Comment: What is the output you get? Is it like \uXXXX?

Comment: You might solve your problem by checking out `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html

Comment: The output is like: '\xd9\x87\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd8'

Comment: Where is the output, in a terminal? What version of Python is it being run with? Also, see my answer for a possibility.

Comment: @user3419211, you are sure you are using python3 ? because you should not be seeing repr representation using python3.4

Comment: Are you on Windows? Maybe you don't have the right code page. What is `sys.stdout.encoding`. python will encode to that value when printing.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the [repr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html) output as you call `readlines` which returns a *list* and lists show the repr representation of your data, once you actually print the strings themselves you will see the actual str output, you are also using python2:

```
In [11]: out = readText()

In [12]: print out
['\xda\x95\xdb\x86\xda\x98\xd8\xaa\xd8\xa7\xd9\x86 \xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb4 \xd8\xa8\xdb\x95\xda\x95\xdb\x8e\xd8\xb2\xd8\xa7\xd9\x86. \xd9\x85\xd9\x86 \xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd9\x85 \xda\x95\xdb\x95\xd9\x86\xd8\xac\xdb\x95. ']

In [13]: print out[0]
ڕۆژتان باش بەڕێزان. من ناوم ڕەنجە.
```

Comment: Yes this is only true when I give it an index. This does not work when I read an article from text file A and write it into text file or json file B

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to take a stab here and guess that you are reading the output in a terminal of some sort, and when Python writes to the terminal it's trying to display in ASCII.

If you set your `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to `UTF-8` this can sometimes solve the issue - it depends on other variables as well.

So, if you're on a UNIX-like system, try this in your terminal: `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`

Or, for Windows, `set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`.

Then, try running your script again and see if you get the correct characters printed.

More information can be found here: [How to print UTF-8 Encoded Text to the console in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741574/how-to-print-utf-8-encoded-text-to-the-console-in-python-3)

Comment: Care to explain downvotes? I don't see why that's really necessary.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but here's two guesses - 1) Your answer doesn't solve the question. 2) By your own admittance, it's a total guess. We ought to understand issues before offering solutions

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Thanks for the constructive feedback, I'll keep my answer here as it may help point someone in the right direction in the future.