# Should I include this boilerplate code in every Python script I write?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

My boss asked me to put the following lines (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4374457/)) into a Python 3 script I wrote:

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
```

He says it's to prevent `UnicodeEncodeErrors` when printing Unicode characters in non-UTF8 locales. I am wondering whether this is really necessary, and why Python wouldn't handle encoding/decoding correctly without boilerplate code.

What is the most Pythonic way to make Python scripts compatible with different operating system locales? And what does this boilerplate code do exactly?

Comment: Did you read the most upvoted answer, that starts with "Eek! Is that a well-known idiom in Python 2? It looks like a dangerous mistake to me."   Furthermore, that was recommended for python2 and even the question specifically says it doesn't work in python3!   Elsewhere, answers to that same question point out "
sys.stdout is in text mode in Python 3. Hence you write unicode to it directly, and the idiom for Python 2 is no longer needed."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11742928/) has a good excerpt from the Python mailing list regarding your question. I guess it is not necessary to do this.

> The only supported default encodings in Python are:
>
> Python 2.x: ASCII
>   Python 3.x: UTF-8
>
> If you change these, you are on your own and strange things will start
>   to happen. The default encoding does not only affect the translation
>   between Python and the outside world, but also all internal
>   conversions between 8-bit strings and Unicode.
>
> Hacks like what's happening in the pango module (setting the default
>   encoding to 'utf-8' by reloading the site module in order to get the
>   sys.setdefaultencoding() API back) are just downright wrong and will
>   cause serious problems since Unicode objects cache their default
>   encoded representation.
>
> Please don't enable the use of a locale based default encoding.
>
> If all you want to achieve is getting the encodings of stdout and
>   stdin correctly setup for pipes, you should instead change the
>   .encoding attribute of those (only).
>
> --
>   Marc-Andre Lemburg
>   eGenix.com