# Unicode, Printing to stdout, what is happening?

Tags: python, unicode

I have problems with printing data to stdout.  I understand the concept of Unicode and Ascii, but I fail to see why a printing instruction doesn't work.

I'm playing with data from a JSON file of a computer game, Fallout Shelter.

when I try to print the data with :

```
   for i in jsondata["dwellers"]["dwellers"]:
        print "{},{} {},{}".format(f,i["name"],i["lastName"],i["relations"])
```

I get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\FOSScript\Tree.py", line 81, in <module>
    tree()
  File "f:\FOSScript\Tree.py", line 76, in tree
    graphing(jsondata)
  File "f:\FOSScript\Tree.py", line 35, in graphing
    print "{} {}".format(i["name"],i["lastName"])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The u'\xe9' is an french accent.

But in the code, when I do :

```
prenom = u'Val\xe9rie'
print prenom
```

The name is printed correctly.

The following instructions :

```
print locale.getpreferredencoding()
print sys.stdout.encoding
```

print the following:

```
cp1252
cp850
```

Both Code pages (as checked on Wikipedia) contain the accent characters.

I am on Windows 10, a French-Canada version.  Python 2.7.13.

==========================

- Why does printing from the table doesn't work, but printing the variable works?
- On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741574/how-to-print-utf-8-encoded-text-to-the-console-in-python-3) page, there is a comment saying

> The only supported default encodings in Python are:
>
> Python 2.x: ASCII
>    Python 3.x: UTF-8

When they say ASCII, do they mean an extended ASCII with accents, since the JSON data contains the accents, python is just "unable" to print it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to use string formatting on a non-unicode string with unicode characters. Instead you want:

```
for i in jsondata["dwellers"]["dwellers"]:
        print u"{},{} {},{}".format(f,i["name"],i["lastName"],i["relations"])
```

Notice the extra u before the quote in the second line.

Testing this on python 2.7

```
print u"{}".format(u'\xe9')
```

works fine.