# Unicode decode error using codecs.open()

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have run into a character encoding problem as follows:

```py
rating = 'Barntillåten'
new_file = codecs.open(os.path.join(folder, "metadata.xml"), 'w', 'utf-8')
new_file.write(

"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <ratings>
        <rating system="%s">%s</rating>
   </ratings>""" % (values['rating_system'], rating))
```

The error I get is:

```py
  File "./assetshare.py", line 314, in write_file
    </ratings>""" % (values['rating_system'], rating))
```

I know that the encoding error is related to `Barntillåten`, because if I replace that word with `test`, the function works fine.

Why is this encoding error happening and what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rating` must be a Unicode string in order to contain Unicode codepoints.

```
rating = u'Barntillåten'
```

Otherwise, in Python 2, the non-Unicode string `'Barntillåten'` contains bytes (encoded with whatever your [source encoding](http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html) was), not codepoints.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, `codecs.open` expects to read and write `unicode` objects.  You're passing it a `str`.

The fix is to ensure that the data you pass it is `unicode`:

```
new_file.write((

"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
"""<ratings>
        <rating system="%s">%s</rating>
   </ratings>""" % (values['rating_system'], rating)
).decode('utf-8'))
```

If you use `unicode` literals (`u"..."`) then Python will try to ensure that all data is `unicode`.  Here it would be sufficient to have `rating = u'Barntillåten'`:

```
rating = u'Barntillåten'
new_file = codecs.open(os.path.join(folder, "metadata.xml"), 'w', 'utf-8')
new_file.write(

"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
"""<ratings>
        <rating system="%s">%s</rating>
   </ratings>""" % (values['rating_system'], rating))
```

You can write into a `codecs.open` file a `str` object, but only if the `str` is encoded in the default encoding, which means that for safety that's only safe if the `str` is plain ASCII.  The default encoding is and should be left as ASCII; see [Changing default encoding of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)

Comment: `.decode('utf-8')` assumes that `values['rating_system']` and `rating` are bytes representing utf-8 encoded text. In this case it requires the source code character encdoding to be utf-8. So it is better to use Unicode literals in the first place without `.decode()` later

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `unicode` literals.

```
u'...'
u"..."
u'''......'''
u"""......"""
```