# Regex deleted special character

Tags: java, regex

I'm having the following problem with regex: I've written a program that reads words from some text (txt) files and writes into another file, writing one word per line.

Everything works fine, except if the word read has a special characters `ľščťžýáíé` in it. The regex deletes the char and splits the word where the special char was.

For Example :
Input:

`I am Jožo.`

Output:

```
I
am
Jo
o
```

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
while( (line = br.readLine())!= null ){ 
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w']+");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
}
```

Comment: Try this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python . Do you know what the byte representation of ž is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this regex:

```
Pattern.compile("[\\w']+")
```

Use Unicode based:

```
Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}']+")
```

It is because by default `\\w` in Java matches only ASCII characters, digits 0-9 and underscore.

**Another option** is to use the modifier

```
Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS
```

Like this:

```
Pattern.compile("[\\w']+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)
```

Comment: waiting for possibility of voting -  still timeout here :)

Answer (score -1):

\\w matches only a-z, A-Z and 0-9 (English alphabet plus numbers)
if you want to accept any character except whitespaces as part of a word, use \\S