# Flask-Admin: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, flask, flask-admin

I'm trying to build a back-end interface for my application with flask-admin.
When I try to access the form to create a new entry I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Going through the stack trace, the problem is that some items in my table contain non-ascii characters. How can I solve this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use unicode string, which is like this

```
u"whaterver string"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem with some legacy code. This problem happens whenever you:

1. Use Python 2, and
2. Represent non-ASCII data via `str` (rather than `unicode`) objects, and
3. Your Python system encoding is `ascii` (as is mostly the case).

The second issue may stem from having SQLAlchemy `String` columns where you shold have had `Unicode`, or from writing `'šömething'` when you should have written `u'šömething'' - it may often be quite tricky to pinpoint the actual source of the problem.

It is, however, easy to solve it by [hacking the third component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python) of the equation (which is [not recommended](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/) in general, though). Adding these lines somewhere in your code should fix things (by tucking the actual problem under the carpet):

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, this error is solved by forcing the string array to unicode with the `unicode.encode()` method .

From the [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError) page on the subject

```
>>> u"a".encode("utf-8")
'a'
>>> u"\u0411".encode("utf-8")
'\xd0\x91'
>>> "a".encode("utf-8")         # Unexpected argument type.
'a'
>>> "\xd0\x91".encode("utf-8")  # Unexpected argument type.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in     range(128)
```

---

I suppose this would be best solved by modifying the jinja macro responsible for the field formatting to force the values to unicode.

Comment: thanks for your reply...but I'm pretty lost. How would I do that?