# How can I change python default encoding?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii, decode

I was wondering how can I change python's default encoding to UTF-8? When I print the default encoding in python it says "ascii", does it equals to UTF-8? or do I have to change it?

Comment: What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve? There are plenty of opportunities to avoid automatic encoding, but you need to tell us what your actual problem is here.

Comment: Well, I'm writing a Java server-Python client project, and I have a problem while sending string over the socket. I asked in a previous question and they answered me that my python and java didn't have the same encoding, so the strings are getting some trash.

Comment: You can explicitly encode unicode data to whatever codec you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing default encoding of Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2276200/450517 BUT: you probably don't need it. just encode you output to utf-8