# Printing bytestring via variable

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following Unicode text stored in variable:

```
 myvariable = 'Gen\xe8ve'
```

What I want to do is to print `myvariable` and show this:

```
Genève
```

I tried this but failed:

```
print myvariable.decode('utf-8')
```

What's the right way to do it? At the end I'd like to print the string into a text file. 
I'm using Python 2.7.

**Update:**
Also tried this:

```
In [23]: myvariable = u'Gen\xe8ve'

In [24]: print myvariable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-1eb59a50889d> in <module>()
----> 1 print myvariable

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Update 2**:
I really want to print from `myvariable`. In actual code `Gen\xe8ve` are extracted from [xml.etree.ElemTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) parser, like:

```
myvariable = actress.find('name').text
## The following doesn't work. 
# print u'myvariable'
```

Comment: You need to know the encoding of your XML. If it's UTF8 and it contains an \xe8 byte, then it's simply a bad file.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` You are right. Is there a way I can use ElemTree to parse it under UTF-8 format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print a unicode string directly

```
myvariable = u'Gen\xe8ve'
print myvariable
```

python tries to encode it with the default encoding (`sys.stdout.encoding`). Since it appears to be `ascii` on your system, it tries ascii and fails (there's no such thing as `\xe8` in ascii). Try specifying the encoding explicitly:

```
myvariable = u'Gen\xe8ve'
print myvariable.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks but see my Update2 and the [real issue under XML link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825149/parsing-xml-file-with-utf-8-encoding-and-bytestring-using-elemtree)

Comment: @pdubois: the answer stands: `encode` everything you're printing.

Comment: thanks a million. Is there a way to define that encoding globally without having to give `.encode('utf-8')` for every variable?

Comment: @pdubois: some ways are outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python

Answer (score 1):

That's not Unicode text, that's a bytestring. *This* is Unicode text:

```
myvariable = u'Gen\xe8ve'
print myvariable
```

Comment: That's an issue with your REPL, not Python.

Comment: What would `\xe8` mean in a Unicode string? Woudln't that depend on your source file encoding? It's not UTF8.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: It would be U+00E8, LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE.

Comment: I didn't know, I thought you had to use \u for that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`'\xe8'` isn't UTF8, it's some other encoding.

Try:

```
>>> x = 'Gen\xc3\xa8ve'
>>> print x.decode('utf8')
```

Or find out what the encoding actually is, and decode that.