# Handling print() UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I extract unicode text from a website and do some printing that can contain non-ascii characters. Printing those raises a `UnicodeEncodeError`. How should I handle this case? I need a solution that requires *minimum changes* to the existing code.

I tried encoding the strings (by wrapping `sys.stdout`) with UTF-8, but then I get a `TypeError` since the original `sys.stdout.write()` method expects `str` not `bytes`.

I don't want the characters to be lost. The user may want to pipe the output into a file that would in this case be UTF8 formatted.

---

Edit: Setting `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` can fix the problem, but isn't there a way I can "imitate" this behaviour in Python? Since utf8 doesn't match the Windows console encoding, some characters look strange. But this is by far better than a crash of the program.

Anyway to format the output from Python so I don't need to modify environment variables?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python

Comment: How can I make `reload(sys).setdefaultencoding` work in Python 3?

Comment: Ok wait, using `export PYTHONIOENCODING="utf8"` works. Still feels clunky... I can "control" that the program raises an Exception from an Environment Variable.