# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7

when i run my code i get this error:

```
UserId = "{}".format(source[1]) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code is:

```
def view_menu(type, source, parameters):
    ADMINFILE = 'static/users.txt'
    fp = open(ADMINFILE, 'r')
    users = ast.literal_eval(fp.read())
    if not parameters:
        if not source[1] in users:
            UserId = "{}".format(source[1])
            users.append(UserId)
            write_file(ADMINFILE,str(users))
            fp.close()
            reply(type, source, u"test")
        else:
            reply(type, source, u"test")

register_command_handler(view_menu, 'test', ['info','muc','all'], 0, '')
```

Please how i can solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: It's worth pointing out here that this problem is exactly why Python 3.x exists. Are you sure you want to learn all the clumsy stuff necessary to deal with mixing Unicode and non-Unicode strings in an old version of the language just to learn everything all over again in a year or two, rather than just learning the easier and newer way now?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `"{}"` is non-Unicode `str`, and you're trying to `format` a `unicode` into it. Python 2.x handles that by automatically encoding the `unicode` with `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which is usually `'ascii'`, but you have some non-ASCII characters.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Explicitly encode that `unicode` in the appropriate character set. For example, if it's UTF-8, do `"{}".format(source[1].encode('utf-8'))`.
2. Use a `unicode` format string: `u"{}".format(source[1])`. You may still need to `encode` that `UserId` later; I have no idea how your `write_file` function works. But it's generally better to keep everything Unicode as long as possible, only encoding and decoding at the very edges, than to try to mix and match the two.

All that being said, this line of code is useless. `"{}".format(foo)` converts `foo` to a `str`, and then formats it into the exact same `str`. Why?

Comment: thank you. now it is work when i use `"{}".format(source[1].encode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score 5):

Take these functions here when handling strings of unknown encoding:

You want to work with the text?

```
def read_unicode(text, charset='utf-8'):
    if isinstance(text, basestring):
        if not isinstance(text, unicode):
            text = unicode(obj, charset)
    return text
```

You want to store the text, for example in a database, use this:

```
def write_unicode(text, charset='utf-8'):
    return text.encode(charset)
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution is to set a default encoding to utf-8 instead of ascii in your sitecustomize.py

[Changing default encoding of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)

Answer (score -2):

Your file `static/users.txt` must contain any non-unicode characters. You must specify any encoding in your program. for intsnace `utf-8`. You can read more about it here: [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: A character whose identity is not assigned by means of the Unicode tables.

Comment: @amatellanes please can you check this quenstions `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088887/nimbuzz-login-config-code-dosnt-work` and help me with my problem.

Comment: @amatellanes: His file almost certainly does not contain any non-Unicode characters. And, if it did, UTF-8 wouldn't help, because UTF-8 only encodes Unicode characters.