# 'ascii' codec can't encode error when reading using Python to read JSON

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Yet another person unable to find the correct magic incantation to get Python to print UTF-8 characters.

I have a JSON file. The JSON file contains string values. One of those string values contains the character "à". I have a Python program that reads in the JSON file and prints some of the strings in it. Sometimes when the program tries to print the string containing "à" I get the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is hard to reproduce. Sometimes a slightly different program is able to print the string "à". A smaller JSON file containing only this string does not exhibit the problem. If I start sprinkling `encode('utf-8')` and `decode('utf-8')` around the code it changes what blows up in unpredictable ways. I haven't been able to create a minimal code fragment and input that exhibits this problem.

I load the JSON file like so.

```
with codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    j = json.load(f)
```

I'll pull out the offending string like so.

```
s = j['key']
```

Later I do a `print` that has `s` as part of it and see the error.

I'm pretty sure the original file is in UTF-8 because in the interactive command line

```
codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8').read()
```

returns a string but

```
codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'ascii').read()
```

gives an error about the ascii codec not being able to decode such-and-such a byte. The file size in bytes is identical to the number of characters returned by `wc -c`, and I don't see anything else that looks like a non-ASCII character, so I suspect the problem lies entirely with this one high-ASCII "à".

I am not making any explicit calls to `str()` in my code.

I've been through the [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) multiple times. I understand that I'm supposed to "sandwich" unicode handling. I think I'm doing this, but obviously there's something I still misunderstand.

Mostly I'm confused because it seems like if I specify 'utf-8' in the `codecs.open` call, everything should be happening in UTF-8. I don't understand how the ASCII codec still sneaks in.

What am I doing wrong? How do I go about debugging this?

---

*Edit*: Used `io` module in place of `codecs`. Same result.

---

*Edit*: I don't have a minimal example, but at least I have a minimal repro scenario.

I am printing an object derived from the strings in the JSON that is causing the problem. So the following gives an error.

```
print(myobj)
```

(Note that I am using `from __future__ import print_function` though that does not appear to make a difference.)

Putting an `encode('utf-8')` on the end of my object's `__str__` function return value does not fix the bug. However changing the print line to this does.

```
print("%s" % myobj)
```

This looks wrong to me. I'd expect these two print calls to be equivalent.

---

I can make this work by doing the [sys.setdefaultencoding hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python):

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("UTF-8")
```

But this is apparently a bad idea that can make Python malfunction in other ways.

What is the correct way to do this? I tried

```
env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 ./myscript.py
```

but that didn't work. (Unsurprisingly, since the issue is the default encoding, not the io encoding.)

Comment: what is `print(repr(myobj))`?

Comment: print(repr(myobj)) does not throw an error. It prints the repr string as expected. (e.g. escaped "\n" instead of newlines.)

Comment: I've asked what is it (the object that causes the issue) and not whether `repr(myobj)` causes an error (it shouldn't). Do you use a custom object (custom `__unicode__`, `__str__`) to parse json? Why?

Answer (score 3):

When you write directly to a file or redirect stdout to a file or pipe the default encoding is ASCII and you have to encode Unicode strings before writing them. With opened file handles you can set an encoding to have this happen automatically but with `print` you must use an `encode()` method.

```py
print s.encode('utf-8')
```

It is recommended to use the newer `io` module in place of `codecs` because it has an improved implementation and is forward compatible with Py3.x `open()`.

Comment: you should *not* encode Unicode before printing it. Don't hardcode the character encoding of your environment inside your script.  Set proper locale settings (LANG, LC_CTYPE, LC_ALL) and/or `PYTHONIOENCODING` envvar instead.