# how can i change python console encoding MAC OSX

Tags: python, macos, encoding, sublimetext2

I tried all in this interesting thread
[Changing default encoding of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)
but nothing work for me.
I use sublime text and when I try :

```
import sys
print(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

Output is : US-ASCII

I have a python script that works perfectly under Windows (Output is : utf-8)

But on osx 10.10.2, I always have a problem

Another thing that might help for answer,
when I try in python shell (osX) this code :

```
>>> leString = '/Users/djex/Desktop/dosser\ é\ espace'
>>> type(leString)
<class 'str'>

>>> stringNew = leString.encode('utf-8')
>>> type(stringNew)
<class 'bytes'>

>>> print (stringNew)
b'/Users/djex/Desktop/dosser\\ \xc3\xa9\\ espace'

>>> print (stringNew.decode('utf-8'))
/Users/djex/Desktop/dosser\ é\ espace
>>>
```

All is ok.but...

when I try the same thing in sublime text (osX), it does not work

i always have this error

```
unicodeencodeerror 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0300' blabla
```

or error like

```
'str object has no attrbute decode'
```

I do not really understand where my problem comes

Ty for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found,
my problem was in python.sublime-build file

this file does not have "env" line

```
{
"cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",
"encoding": "utf-8",
"env": {"LANG": "fr_FR.UTF-8"}
}
```