# Python 3 set default bytes encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, byte

In Python 3, `bytes` requires an encoding:

```
bytes(s, encoding="utf-8")
```

Is there a way to set a default encoding, so `bytes` always encodes in UTF-8?

The simplest way I imagine is

```
def bytes_utf8(s):
    return bytes(s, encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation for `bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) redirects you to the [documentation for `bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray), which says in part:

> The optional source parameter can be used to initialize the array in a few different ways:
>
> - If it is a string, you must also give the encoding (and optionally, errors) parameters; bytearray() then converts the string to bytes using str.encode().

It looks like there's no way to provide a default.

You can use the `encode` method, which *does* have a default, given by `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. If you need to change the default, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python) but be aware that the capability to do it easily was removed for good reason.

```
import sys
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
s.encode()
```