# Python3 UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a Django 1.8 app running on a server with Python 3 and I get a UnicodeDecodeError when logging and printing strings with special characters.

`>:python --version
   python 3.4.3`

For example, if I try to run a silly method in the shell:

```
def print_test():
       print('Test: èè') # any 'special char' like ä ç é û...
```

I get a stack trace:

```
>>> print_test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sailingadmin/sailing-admin/utest.py", line 2, in print_test
    print('This is a test: \xe8\xe8')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 16-17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Same with `print(u'Test: èè')`

Why does this error happen?

utest.py is encoded in utf-8 (Python 3 default for source files)

`>:echo $LC_CTYPE
   UTF-8`

All logging and printing raises a UnicodeEncodeError...

Comment: What's important here are the LC_* environment variable _used by your server process_ - not the ones defined for your own user account. You may want to check your process's environment and front-end server config.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Do you mean the `/proc/<id>/environ`? LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 and LANG=en_US.UTF-8, no other encoding variables are set there.

Comment: I mean "the environment variables of the process which stdout will be used by your process"...  Sorry I've not had to deal with this kind of problem for quite a few years now (thanks to our sysadmin <g>), so I don't remember all the gory details :-/

Comment: Take a look here, maybe that will help you set the encoding back to UTF-8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python

Comment: @Maciek this does not apply to python 3, reload is not a builtin. (but it is importable)

Comment: @Ire can you check what is your default locale while executing the script using locale.getlocale() and locale.getpreferredencoding()? And do you use the internationalization features of Django?

Comment: @Maciek locale.getlocale() returns (None, None) and getprefferedencoding() returns 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
I am trying to find out where this value comes from!

Comment: LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 wasn't valid. Set it to en_US.UTF-8, and now the errors are gone! Thanks!

Comment: Add an answer to your question then and accept it after 48 hours :)

Answer (score 2):

LC_CTYPE format as follows: `en_US.UTF-8` (char map after the dot)
Then python uses it as default encoding for logging and io.