# python3 UnicodeDecodeError while logging to console

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode, python-logging

I just ported my webapp to python 3. I develop in my Mac and deploy in a CentOS server. I found many `UnicodeDecodeError` that don't happen in my local test environment but they appear in the deployment server (of course :D )

Most of them I fixed by specifiying the encoding when opening files. However there is one place where I don't know how to specify encoding and it is in logging. I still get errors such as:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xab' in position 85: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The same problem existed (in both platforms) in python 2 and it was solved with this

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Which changed the value of `sys.getdefaultencoder()` from `ascii` to `utf-8`

But now in python3 `sys.getdefaultencoder()` is already `utf-8` by default ( [Why should we NOT use sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") in a py script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script) ) so I'm clueless on what's causing this difference of behavior.

So:

- what should I look for to see why both platforms are having different defaults for encoding?
- how can I solve this for logging?

Comment: Just get the repr of the string.

Comment: @InfectedDrake The solution can't be to modify all places where I log something (!!) especially if this does work in one computer and doesnt in another and it did work in python2 in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here [Python3 UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955276/python3-unicodedecodeerror/34092363#34092363). Let me expand:

This is solved by setting the environment value `LC_CTYPE` to `en_US.UTF-8` instead of `UTF-8`. This can be set in `.bashrc`:

`export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`

Strangely enough, both my mac and deployment server have `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` and in my mac it just works, but in the deployment server I need to set it to `en_US.UTF-8` otherwise it won't work.

But this seems like a weird config from my deployment server because if I set it to `UTF-8` it complains like this:

```
$ export LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

(My mac doesnt complain).

So obviously python is not reading `LC_CTYPE` directly but rather reading something else (a locale?) that is set by setting `LC_CTYPE`.