# How to see unicode (utf-8) __repr__ for class in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, repr

**What I would like**

In this example, I would like to see the unicode string without using `print`:

```
In [1]: a = u's·A/m'

In [2]: type(a)
Out[2]: str

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 's\xc2\xb7A/m'

In [4]: print a
s·A/m
```

How to force string `__repr__` not to display `s\xc2\xb7A/m` but `s·A/m` instead?

**What is the use-case?**

I have a class that represents a number in association with its units for example:

```
class MyNumber(float):
    def __new__(cls, ...): 
        ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self) + str(self.units)
```

When I am working in IPython I would like to quickly see the content of instance:

```
>>> a = MyNumber('23.43', ampere=1, second=1, meter=-1)
>>> a
23.43 s·A/m
```

Instead I get an exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And If I try to manually see the content of my `__repr__` I get this:

```
>>>a.__repr__()
23.43 s\xc2\xb7A/m
```

Comment: @nowox What's `type(a.__repr__())` and where exactly does your exception occur (this is shown by the so-called traceback of the exception which waits to be edited into the question)?

Comment: `type(a.__repr__())` is `str`

Comment: You've tagged the question `python-2.7` but you're IPython output says `type(a)` is `str` on line `[2]`.  It should say `<type 'unicode'>`.  Then, `[3]` shows it as a UTF-8-encoded byte string.  This doesn't look like it was cut-n-pasted from a real trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a byte string from `__repr__`, return a Unicode string.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return unicode(self) + self.units.decode('utf-8')
```

If `self.units` is already a Unicode string:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return unicode(self) + self.units
```

Comment: @nowox you can't `decode` a Unicode string, if you try Python will try to `encode` it first which is what generates the error. Did you even try the code I give here?

Comment: Sorry, your final conclusion is opposite of what I was saying. You are returning a byte string, and I said to return a Unicode string. Did you try it my way?

Comment: @nowox I mean neither! `decode` converts a byte string to a Unicode string, and `encode` converts a Unicode string to a byte string. Just stick to Unicode strings throughout and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem may comes from your IPython configuration. Check the encoding:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
```

If you get ASCII as above, you may experience some issues with unicode strings.

So try this:

```
>>> reload(sys)
>>> sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

And it should works...

Comment: Setting resp. changing the default encoding may lead to severe issues with programs which expect the default one. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17628350/296974) which links to [here](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/).

Comment: Damned. I guess I am still confused about this encoding issue. If this is not the solution to my problem. What should I do [glglgl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/296974/glglgl).

Comment: The problem is, `sys.setdefaultencoding` sets the default program-wide and thus affects as well parts which are not aware of the change. Instead, every place where a encode or decode happens should be provided with the knowledge which encoding should be used.

Answer (score -2):

It is a so-called XY problem. Your first question is completely irrelevant.

Instead, you should

- either fix your `self.units` to be in the right format (if I am not mistaken, you use Python 3? You should announce your Python major version in the tags...)
- or convert it to something like

  ```
  class MyNumber(float):
      def __repr__(self):
          return str(self) + " " + str(self.units)
  ```

This answer results of my guess that `self.units` is maybe not a `str`, but a `unicode` object. Then its implicit conversion could fail as per default, the `ascii` codec is used for decoding.

You should make sure not to mix up raw strings and unicode strings.

If `str(self.units)` doesn't work, you might want to replace it with `self.units.decode("utf8")`.

To become clear about the process:

Typing `a` at the prompt will display the result of `repr(a)`, somehow.

`repr(a)` calls `a.__repr__()`, **checks its type (it must be `str`)** and displays it.

I am not clear about why `a` or `repr(a)` fails while `a.__repr__()` works, that's why I keep asking about the exception's traceback...

Comment: Doing `return "%s %s" % (str(self), self.units)` gives the same result

Comment: It's a bad idea to `str()` without giving an encoding. Any non ASCII chars will throw a UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack This is true for `unicode` objects. But we still don't know where exactly the error happens and what exactly happens, as we still don't see the traceback of the exception, and we still don't know if `self.units` is `str` or `unicode`, so we'll have to try an iterative approach to the solution. That's what I try to make clear in the answer although some people seem to think there's something wrong with it...