# Python encoding unicode<>utf-8

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding, utf-8

So I am getting lost somewhere in converting unicode to utf-8. I am trying to define some JSON containing unicode characters, and writing them to file. When printing to the terminal the character is represented as '\u2606'. When having a look at the file the character is encoded to '\u2606', note the double backslash. Could someone point me into the right direction regarding these encoding issues?

```
# encoding=utf8

import json

data = {"summary" : u"This is a unicode character: ☆"}
print data

decoded_data = unicode(data)
print decoded_data

with open('decoded_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(decoded_data, outfile)
```

I tried adding the following snippet to the head of my file, but this had no success neither.

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour and switch to Python 3 if possible. In Python 2 the separation of unicode and encoded data is not strict and this may hide programming errors.

Comment: @phobie: ^ **bad** advice... *never* try to "hide" programming errors, as there shouldn't be any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are printing the representation of a dictionary, and python only uses ascii characters and escapes any other character with `\uxxxx`.

The same is with `json.dump` trying to only use ascii characters. You can force `json.dump` to use unicode with:

```
json_data = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)
with open('decoded_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_data.encode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also refer to this link.It is also really useful

[Set Default Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)