# Persist UTF-8 as Default Encoding

Tags: python, utf-8, utf

I tried to persist UTF-8 as the default encoding in Python.

I tried:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
```

And I also tried:

```
>>> import sys
>>> reload(sys)
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'UTF8'
>>>
```

But after closing the session and opening a new session, the following was the result:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
```

**How can I persist my changes?** (I know that it's not always a good idea to change to UTF-8. It's in a Docker container of Python).

I know it's possible. I saw someone who has UTF-8 as his default encoding (always).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look into [site.py](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) library - it is the place where `sys.setdefaultencoding` happens. You could, I think, modify or substitute this module in order to make it permanent on your machine. Here is some of it's source code, comments explains something:

```
def setencoding():
    """Set the string encoding used by the Unicode implementation.  The
    default is 'ascii', but if you're willing to experiment, you can
    change this."""

    encoding = "ascii" # Default value set by _PyUnicode_Init()
    if 0:
        # Enable to support locale aware default string encodings.
        import locale
        loc = locale.getdefaultlocale()
        if loc[1]:
            encoding = loc[1]
    if 0:
        # Enable to switch off string to Unicode coercion and implicit
        # Unicode to string conversion.
        encoding = "undefined"
    if encoding != "ascii":
        # On Non-Unicode builds this will raise an AttributeError...
        sys.setdefaultencoding(encoding) # Needs Python Unicode build !
```

Full source https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/site.py.

This is the place where they delete the `sys.setdefaultencoding` function, if you were wondering:

```
def main():

    ...

    # Remove sys.setdefaultencoding() so that users cannot change the
    # encoding after initialization.  The test for presence is needed when
    # this module is run as a script, because this code is executed twice.
    if hasattr(sys, "setdefaultencoding"):
        del sys.setdefaultencoding
```

Answer (score 5):

First, this is almost certainly a bad idea, since code will mysteriously break if you run it on a different machine where this configuration hasn't been done.

(1) Create a new file like this (mine's called `setEncoding.py`):

```
import sys
# reload because Python removes setdefaultencoding() from the namespace
# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

(2) set the environment variable `[PYTHONSTARTUP][1]` to point at this file.

(3) When the Python interpreter is loaded, the code inside the file that `PYTHONSTARTUP` points at will be executed first:

```
bgporter@Ornette ~/temp:python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always add at the top of your python files:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Which will in *nix systems change the encoding to utf-8 for that file.

Comment: You can alternatively define other encodings using the same format. It must be the first or second line of the file though. Details behind it here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: The OP is working with a terminal (that's why he's saying closing/opening sesions), not with files.

Comment: thanks, but I don't have the permission to change the files.

Comment: This trick not change anything always. Decode objects before processing.