# Python - file.write() causes chinese text

Tags: python-3.5

When I write a certain string to a file in an infinite loop, for example:

```
file = open('txt.txt', 'w')
while 1:
    file.write('colour')
```

It gives me all this chinese text:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTgpx.png)

Why does this happen?

Comment: This works for me and may be just an encoding issue of your text editor. Have you tried viewing it in another program? Also, it would be interesting how a pure ASCII dump looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same result by copy pasting `colour` several times in notepad then saving and reloading the file. There's nothing wrong with your python code. The bytes written to the file will look something like this (in hex):

```
63 CF 6C 6F 75 72  63 CF 6C 6F 75 72 ...
```

When notepad reads these bytes it needs to guess what they represent. It would ideally decode the text as utf-8 or ascii. Instead it sees a pattern in the bytes and guesses wrong.

I noticed that every pair of bytes corresponds to one chinese character. This suggests the encoding might be utf-16. The following test in python confirms that this is the case:

```
>>> original = 'colour' * 100
>>> original.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-16')
\u6f63\u6f6c\u7275\... # repeating
```

These code points correspond to 潣, 潬, and 牵 which is the same thing that notepad displays. So the issue is that notepad is incorrectly decoding your bytes as utf-16 instead of utf-8. This is reminiscent of the old [Bush hid the facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) bug.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your encoding is set as an inproper default (possible on install or based on your computers settings)

you can change it by:

```
import sys
reload(sys)  # Reload does the trick!
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

Check this thread out  for more info
[Changing default encoding of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)

Comment: Nope this problem isn't on python's end, it's notepad.

Comment: Hmm.... It's possible. I just assumed we needed to hear what OP had to say to Monkey Supersonic's suggestion (which follows your thought).

Comment: Yup Monkey Supersonic was right. It's not hard to reproduce the problem using only notepad, or even a hex editor. The utf-8 bytes are misinterpreted as utf-16 by notepad.