# printing out card suits symbols in python 3

Tags: python, ascii, python-3.5

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from io import TextIOWrapper
sys.stdout = TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding='UTF-8', errors='replace')

print('♥')
```

I have problems with printing out the suits symbols in Windows console I search the internet for 2 days but found nothing how to make the console able to print these symbols. It seems to work in any other platform like Linux... I tried the solution provided above to import some modules and change the encoding of the system. it works but after 2 hours the console starts printing Latin characters instead e.g ē Does not make any sense
i really need help i have to do this before the submition day on next friday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**1**) Set `PYTHONIOENCODING` system variable:

```
 set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8"
```

(**2**) [Change the active console Code Page to `UTF-8`](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html).

**Script** (note that all the `sys.stdout = …` stuff is commented out):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# import sys
# from io import TextIOWrapper
# sys.stdout = TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding='UTF-8', errors='replace')

print('♥')
```

**Output** (`Copy&Paste` from an open `cmd` window):

```
==> set pyth
PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

==> chcp
Active code page: 852

==> D:\test\Python\40496821.py
ÔÖą

==> chcp 437
Active code page: 437

==> D:\test\Python\40496821.py
ΓÖÑ

==> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

==> D:\test\Python\40496821.py
♥

==>
```

Comment: sorry, but I did not get what you mean by changing the active console mode

Comment: @FaisalJulaidan please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40496821/edit) and provide what do you get for various `chcp`s (like I did). Read [Changing default encoding of Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python).

Comment: On Windows 7, that causes `LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001` in Python.