# Python missing iso-8859-1 when running as service

Tags: python, ubuntu, service, ascii, iso-8859-1

I have a very simple python command

```
python3 -c "print(b'\xe9'.decode('iso-8859-1'))"
```

When I run it from the command prompt it works fine. However, if I wrap it in a service and place it in `/etc/init/test_service` like this

```
description "test of iso-8859-1 issue"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid www-data
setgid www-data


script
        exec python3 -c "print(b'\xe9'.decode('iso-8859-1'))"
end script
```

Then it fails with error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Most of the other answers I've found don't assume you need to install something to make `iso-8859-1` available.

Comment: Presumably the locale etc when running as root is different. Try the usual workarounds to set an explicit encoding for standard output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing default encoding of Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)

Comment: Interesting the issue is with the printing to the command line.

Comment: `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python3 -c "print(b'\xe9'.decode('iso-8859-1'))"` works for me, but without knowledge of your locale, it's unclear whether the result I get is the one you expect.

Comment: Does it fail if you dont have the PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8

Comment: Yes, it does. Docker mint Ubuntu image (modulo `apt-get update; apt-get install -y python3`) running as root.