# UnicodeEncodeError odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

This is my code in .py file:

```
description_val = str(self.description)
```

also I'm try:

```
description_val = str(self.description).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

I don't ignore special character et. Malmö  --> Malm

Get this error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0160' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

How fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve via changing default encoding of python.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

You can follow below link for default **system encoding & change encoding**.

[Changing default encoding of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)