# How are these characters different?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I'm not sure why these characters are different since they appear to be the same visually. Are they different representations of the same character? or actually different characters? Is there a method to check their equality that would result in `True`?

```
>>> s = u'\u2022' 
>>> ss = '•'
>>> s == ss
False
>>> print u'\u2022' , '•'
• •
>>> ss = unicode(ss)
>>> ss == s
False
>>> repr(ss)
"u'\\xe2\\x80\\xa2'"
>>> repr(s)
"u'\\u2022'"
```

Comment: Try `ss.decode('utf-8') == s`

Comment: They are the same character `BULLET`, this issue has to do with Python's `unicode` type, I guess. If you don't want to face such issues, you can switch to Python 3.

Comment: Try the same thing in Python 3 and you will have your personal reason why you should use Python 3 instead of Python 2.

Comment: There is, in fact, a way to get them to compare equal. But you shouldn't use it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python (Set the "default encoding" to UTF-8 instead of ASCII or Latin-1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`u"\u2022"` (your `s`) is a Unicode string (type `unicode`) containing the bullet character.

`"\xe2\x80\xa2"` (your `ss`) is a byte string (type `str`) containing the three bytes used to encode the bullet character as UTF-8.

You can convert one to the other using `str.decode` and `unicode.decode`:

```
>>> s_encode = s.encode("UTF-8")
>>> s_encode == ss
True

>>> ss_decode = ss.decode("UTF-8")
>>> ss_decode == s
True
```

Comment: This can be seen at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm under encodings