# There are non ascii character in path of "static" folder in flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

This is a code in css

```
background-image: url( {{ url_for('static', filename = 'background.jpg') }} ) ;
```

And the path for static is "/Users/gengruijie/Desktop/未命名文件夹/OneDrive/学习/cs/课外/Github/AutoGrading/sample". So it will give me a error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 892, in send_static_file
    cache_timeout=cache_timeout)
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 633, in send_from_directory
    filename = safe_join(directory, filename)
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 603, in safe_join
    return os.path.join(directory, filename)
  File "/Users/gengruijie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 73, in join
    path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My Python version is 2.7.12
My flask version is '0.11.1'

Comment: You can try running [`import sys; reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628350/8200485) but that can break things.

Comment: At the top of your code, you can also try adding [`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). I'm not sure if either of these solutions work though because I can't try them right now.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino: it works!! Thank you very much