# Python 2.7 file encoding fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

When I am using Python 2.7 and trying to declare Python source code encoding by:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

When I am checking file encoding by:

```
check_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()
logger.warning("check_encoding ")
```

I am getting:

```
ascii
```

When I am using Python 3 I have no problem with that by declaring source code encoding by:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

When I am checking file encoding by:

```
check_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()
logger.warning("check_encoding ")
```

I am getting:

```
utf-8
```

I have no idea what's wrong with Python 2.7 version and what can cause it.

Comment: The encoding of your Python script and the encoding used by I/O functions such as `read()` or `input()` are two completely different and unrelated things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why encoding in utf-8 still results in ascii?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413726/why-encoding-in-utf-8-still-results-in-ascii)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the source code encoding (declared with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*`) and the default run time encoding with is used for implicit conversions between unicode and byte strings. They are totally unrelated in both Python 2 and Python 3.

In that sense `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*` behaves exactly the same in Python 2 and Python 3: it declares the encoding of unicode litterals in the current source file.

But the system default encoding is different. It is normally ascii in Python 2 and can depend on environment on Python 3 with a default of UTF-8. So you get the same value in your code only by accident...