# How to list the .xlsb file names in a folder?

Tags: python, unicode

I have these lines to get filenames in a folder.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import os, sys

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

file_folder = "C:\\tem\\"

root, dirs, files = os.walk(file_folder).next()

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for f in files:
        print file_folder + f
```

It doesn’t work when the folder contains .xlsb files. (Excel Binary Workbook file)

The error returned is:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

I tried changed the last line to encode/decode to make them work but still can’t.

How can I have them displayed properly?

Comment: I don't think it's because of the file extension but rather the file name.  What are the full path + file name to the files that failed?  Or maybe just don't set the system default encoding at all.

Comment: @Idlehands, you are right, it's not about the file extension. actually the problem lies in file names. let me delete this question in 10 minutes. anyway if the file names contains non utf-8 characters, the lines shall be working...

Comment: check out the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python#17628350  Python 3 is the fix.  but if you absolutely need python2 then try print(u"{}".format(file_folder + f))  it could help.

Comment: @Back2Basics, thank you for the link and the line. tried print(u"{}".format(file_folder + f)) and it still cann't. the reason being some file names contains a dash.

Comment: @MarkK maybe instead of `setdefaultencoding()` you can `getdefaultencoding()` instead? I'm not sure what's your purpose for that line but `os.walk()` shouldn't require encoding.  Have you tried running without that line? Also dashes *shouldn't* cause the error... unless they're some special characters that looks like a dash but isn't.

Comment: I suggest using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob) in the standard library.

Comment: @Idlehands, thank you for the follow-up. i tried getdefaultencoding() and it returns the same warning. further, i don't use os.walk() and use os.listdir to list the files, still the same...

Comment: @martineau, thank you. I tried glob but returned the same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output terminal doesn't handle the Unicode characters in some of your filenames.  The easiest solution is to write the output to a UTF-8-encoded file and then read the result with a Unicode-capable editor using a font that supports the Unicode characters used.  Another solution where you can still use `print` is to get a UTF-8-capable IDE.

```
#!python2
import os,io

root = u'C:\\tem'  # Use a Unicode root with os.walk() to get Unicode filenames.

with io.open('files.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as out:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for f in files:
            out.write(os.path.join(path,f) + u'\n')
```

Notes:

- `#coding:utf8` only declares the encoding of the *source file*.  If your source is all ASCII characters it doesn't do anything.
- https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/

Comment: thank you. i follow the same and it still gives "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 68: ordinal not in range(128)". it works fine if the folder doesn't contain the files of names contain the look like dash.

Comment: @MarkK  you used the *exact* code above?  That particular error only occurs if you mix byte strings and Unicode strings.

Comment: superb! excuse mine carelessness. the u' matters for the root path. if there's no u', it doesn't work. with the u', it works perfectly!