# How to remove certain utf-8 characters from a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

In my case I want to remove specifically the `„` and the `”` characters from a string. I use BeautifulSoup to parse certain html paragraphs, and get a substring from them. So far my code looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

soup = bs(open("file.xhtml"), 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all('p', {"class": "fnp2"}) :
    line = unicode(str(tag).split(':')[0], "utf-8")
    line = re.sub('(<p class="fnp2">)(\d+) ', '', line)
    line = line.replace('„', '')
    print line
```

But for that, I always receive a `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
line = line.replace('„', '')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position
0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What would be a solution for this?

Comment: Does your .xhtml specify an encoding?

Comment: Try changing the problematic line to line.replace(u'„', ''). It may also be the case that you are getting the error in the "print" statement, however. Finally, make sure your script file is actually saved in cp1252 (or better, use UTF8 for all of your code, always, and mark it in the header).

Comment: Have you tried `open("file.xhtml", encoding='utf-8')`?

Comment: @lit Yes it does:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">`

Comment: @KT. Thank you. It seems like `line.replace(u'„', '')` was the answer. How can I make sure the script file is saved in cp1252, other than writing `# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-` at the start of the file? 

@lit and @TigerhawkT3 thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: The encoding that you save your file in is determined by your text editor. Most editors and IDEs provide a way to specify the encoding (and most save in UTF8 by default, by the way). The line `# -*- coding: ...` is there to tell the Python interpreter the encoding the file was saved in, it does *not* force your editor to save the file in this encoding (unless it is a very smart Python IDE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `line` variable in your code is a `unicode` object. When you call `line.replace` Python expects the first argument to also be a `unicode` object. If you provide a `str` object instead, Python will try to automatically decode it into a `unicode` string using the system default encoding (which you can check via `sys.getdefaultencoding()`).

Apparently, the system encoding is `ascii` in your case. The byte string `'„'` cannot be decoded using the `ascii` codec, because `'„'` is not an ACII symbol, which causes the Exception that you see.

You could fix the problem by [changing the default system encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python) to the same one you used to provide the `'„'` string (CP1252, I guess), however such a fix is only interesting from the academic point of view, as it just sweeps the issue under the carpet.

A proper, safe and easy fix to your problem would be to simply provide a `unicode` object to the `replace` method in the first place. This would be as simple as replacing `'„'` with `u'„'` in your code.