# Tkinter cant decode emojis from entryy

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a sample of my program:

```
import re
import tkinter as T
_nonbmp = re.compile(r'[\U00010000-\U0010FFFF]')

def _surrogatepair(match):
    char = match.group()
    assert ord(char) > 0xffff
    encoded = char.encode('utf-16-le')
    return (
        chr(int.from_bytes(encoded[:2], 'little')) + 
        chr(int.from_bytes(encoded[2:], 'little')))

def createSurrogate(data):
    return _nonbmp.sub(_surrogatepair, data)

def server_send(event=None):
    data = entry_field.get()
    server.send(data, False)
    entry_text.set("")

def insertEmoji(code):
    entry_field.insert("insert", code)

def emoji():
    win = T.Tk()
    win.title("Emojis")
    emoji1 = T.Button(win, text=createSurrogate("\U0001F602"), command=lambda: insertEmoji("\U0001F602"))
    emoji1.pack()
    win.mainloop()

main = T.Tk()
main.title("SDT_Client")
entry_text = T.StringVar()
entry_text.set("")
messages_frame = T.Frame(main)
scrollbar = T.Scrollbar(messages_frame)  
msg_list = T.Listbox(messages_frame, height=15, width=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=T.RIGHT, fill=T.Y)
msg_list.pack(side=T.LEFT, fill=T.BOTH)
msg_list.pack()
messages_frame.pack()

entry_field = T.Entry(main, textvariable=entry_text)
entry_field.bind("<Return>", server_send)
entry_field.pack()
send_button = T.Button(main, text="Send", command=server_send)
send_button.pack()
emojiButton = T.Button(main, text="Emojis", command=emoji)
emojiButton.pack()
```

To summarize i have an entry with a send button underneath and an emoji button further down. When the send button is clicked the contents of the entry is sent to a server. When the emoji button is clicked a new window is open with more buttons with emojis on display. When one of those buttons is clicked the emoji is inserted into the entry field. But when i try to send a message including an emoji i get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\....\nClient.py", line 36, in server_send
    data = entry_field.get()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2682, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I am aware that the problem is occurring in the line:

```
data = entry_field.get()
```

But i am unable to think of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because python uses `utf-8` and emojis use a different codec, here's something I found for you: https://pypi.org/project/emoji-encoding/. If you want to change encoding by yourself here is a SO question I found [Changing default encoding of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python).

### EDIT 1:

Open the code in notepad, then click 'File' then 'Save As' then click 'Encoding: ANSI' then click UTF-8 then confirm with 'Yes'.

You can remove part of the code to decode emojis because python already does that for you :)

(sorry for the stupid first answer btw)