# Identical code works in .ipynb but fails in .py

Tags: python, osmnx, graphml

Using the *OSMnx* package, I am attempting to write a script which involves loading a *.osm* file. The .osm file was downloaded from Geofabrik.

When building, I prefer using *.ipynb* on VS code, but I am running into a seemingly insurmountable error (which, so far, ChatGPT has not been able to help me with) when trying to run it as a *.py* file from command prompt. I am using the same Conda environment for both.

Why is it that the below piece of code works perfectly fine in a *.ipynb* file in VS code, but returns the below error when the exact same code is run in a *.py* file which I am trying to call from command prompt?

**Code:**

```
network = 'network_file.osm'
G = ox.graph_from_xml(network)
```

**Error when run as .py from command prompt:**

```
G = ox.graph_from_xml(network)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Owner\.conda\envs\ox\Lib\site-packages\osmnx\graph.py", line 559, in graph_from_xml
    response_jsons = [osm_xml._overpass_json_from_file(filepath)]
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Owner\.conda\envs\ox\Lib\site-packages\osmnx\osm_xml.py", line 88, in _overpass_json_from_file
    root_attrs = ET.parse(f).getroot().attrib
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Owner\.conda\envs\ox\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1218, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\.conda\envs\ox\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 580, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Owner\.conda\envs\ox\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 8529: character maps to <undefined>
```

**Failed fix attempt:**

ChatGPT had suggested the below, which only returned more errors..

```
with open(network, 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as file:
    G = ox.graph_from_xml(file)

**Error**
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: has the xml file been generated by OSMnx? The documentations warns against this:
"Do not load an XML file generated by OSMnx: this use case is not supported and may not behave as expected." https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html

Are you just passing the file name as a string in the first example?
Are you using the exact same virtual environment in both cases (notebook and py file)?

The second example generated by chatgpt of course wont work because you are opening the file and then passing the opened file, when you are just supposed to pass the path to the file.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment :) Yes I am using the exact same virtual environment. And The XML wasn't generated by OSMnx, but was downloaded from Geofabrik.de. Had the XML been generated by OSMnx, wouldn't it have failed in the .ipynb too? And you're right about the ChatGPT answer, thanks. I tried passing the path to the file, but then found myself with the first error once again.

Comment: maybe you can work around this by changing the default encoding/decoding that python uses. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python

My guess that this default is somehow changed in the notebook implicitly (I am always a bit suspicious of the "ipython magic" stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows character encoding can be a bit of a pain at times. You're probably running into [this issue](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/1083). You can read through that thread for details, but this will be resolved by OSMnx 1.8.0 which should be released within the coming day.

Comment: FYI, v1.8.0 has been released.

Comment: Splendid! Thank you. I'll have another bash at it.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! And thank you for the wonderful OSMnx package!